# Prove that $R(P) = N (I − P) = X$ and $R(I − P) = N (P) = Y$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Suppose that $V = X ⊕Y$, and let $P$ be the projector onto $X$ along
$Y$. Prove that 
$R(P) = N (I − P) = X$ and $R(I − P) = N (P) = Y$.

I know that from $V = X ⊕Y$ I got $v=x+y$ for $v,x,y$ are element of $V,X,Y$ and the intersect of $X$ and $Y$ is zero. But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: With $v = x+y$, can you say what $Pv$ is?

Comment: by definition of $P$, $Pv=x$ so when $v=x+y$, $Pv=v-y$ but I don't understand how this can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: For any $v\in V$, we have $v=P(v)+y,$ where $y=v-P(v)=(I-P)(v).$

Recall that for any linear transformation $T:V\to W,$ we have $$N(T)=\{v\in V:T(v)=0_W\}$$ and $$R(T)=\{w\in W:T(v)=w\text{ for some }v\in V\}.$$

In particular, then, recalling that all $v\in V$ can be uniquely written in the form $x+y$ where $x\in X,y\in Y,$ and so $P(v)=x,$ then $$N(P)=\{v\in V:x=0\}\\R(I-P)=\{w\in V:w=(I-P)(v)=v-P(v)=v-x=y\text{ for some }v\in V\}.$$ It shouldn't be too difficult to show that these two sets are equal, and in particular are equal to $Y$. Similarly, we can show that $N(I-P)=R(P)=X$.

Comment: Can you explain a little further? I didn't understand this chapter very well.

Comment: I actually intended to post an expanded answer yesterday afternoon, but the site went into read-only mode.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For a projection $P$, $P^2 = P$. So, for example, $P(I-P)x = Px - P^2x = Px - Px = 0$.